# C# .NET 4.5 Web Application Remote Desktop single sign on

Tags: .net, remote-desktop

I'm using Windows authentication for an intranet application and am trying to develop a page where a user can create a remote desktop session without having to re-enter their credentials. Currently I just have an image that's linked to an .rdp file, and when they click it the user has to:

a) Click on "Open" when the OS prompts them to, and
b) enter their credentials

Is there any way to skip these two steps so that when the user clicks on the link it just creates a new RDP session with the credentials they've used to authenticate into the web app?

Thanks...

Comment: If this is possible, it'd be a security hole the size of the sun. Just a friendly reminder.

Comment: Machinarius, that's what I've been seeing from my research, but I guess I don't understand why, if it's passing their Windows credentials to the .rdp configuration file (or whatever other mechanism I'm using to authenticate to the RDP session). Thank you, though, for pointing that out, as I certainly don't want to create a security risk in our intranet application. That would be, as they say, a career limiting move.